# bringing the top 5 values, any advice?

Tags: php

I am not an expert on php

So I have a question, is there a shortcut for this code?

The code worked briefly, bringing the top 5 values

> //vid_id.json
> {"video_id":{"nljJo":6,"Eg50":5,"ydIsc":1,"J9-a0":1,"2h8fU":1, ..

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('vid_id.json'), true);
asort($data['video_id']);
$items = array();
foreach ($data['video_id'] as $x => $x_value) {
    $items[] = $x;
}
$c = array_values(array_reverse($items));
$Top5 = null;
$num = 1;
foreach ($c as $key => $value) {
    if (4 >= $key) {
        $Top5 .= $num . " - " . $value . "<br>";
        $key++;
        $num++;
    }
}
echo $Top5;
```

It works very well, but I was wondering if there was a better optimize

Comment: What do you mean by top5? "Top" based on what?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php + https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: Drop the `foreach` and just use `array_keys($data['video_id'])`

Comment: @Jaquarh Thank you for the note

Comment: @FelippeDuarte The highest value of the values,for example {"video_id":{"EnljJo":6,"4Eg50":4}}

Comment: @Skora When you mean shortcut, you mean optimized?

Comment: How do you get highest value from this? Maybe it's better to provide some example of your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` just pulls the `array_keys()` so can be dropped. You can also use `array_splice()` to get the first 5 records as noted in the comments by [Pelippe Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580044/felippe-duarte).

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('vid_id.json'), true);

asort($response);

$top5 = array_splice(                                       // Split
            array_values(                                   // Loose Original Keys
                array_reverse(                              // I Assume For Sorting
                    array_keys($response['video_id'])       // Dropped Foreach
                )
            )
        , 0, 4);                                           // Offset 0, Length
```

**This is untested** as I do not know what your `vid_id.json` holds but theoretically, this should work.

---

`$top5` will now be an array you can loop through on your front-end and output rather than your back-end.

Comment: vid_id.json it contains {"video_id":{"EnljJo":6,"m09Ds":4,"ZcaBZ2ydIsc":1,.. 
And when I tried your code I got an error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: I was missing a `;` after the `json_decode` lol and the `)` was unnecessary. Like I said, its untested. Any syntax errors I'm sure will give you a line. I updated the question with the syntax fixes

Comment: Thank you but I got the last 5 values, I didn't get the highest values from the data

Comment: Probably remove the `array_reverse`, I didn't understand why you was using that anyway

Comment: To make the highest value first at the beginning of the list and then the lowest

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you can make use of data structure called max heap to get the top 5 data. This would also avoid the cost of sorting the entire dataset(of say a million rows).

PHP implements [`SplHeap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php) heap class already. Just impose your own `compare()` method to make it behave like a max heap.

Process is simple. Insert all elements in queue. Extract the top 5 from it.

```
<?php

class MaxHeap extends SplHeap{
    protected function compare($val1, $val2){
        return $val1 <=> $val2;
    }
}

$heap = new MaxHeap();
foreach([8,5,2,0,1,7,9,0,5,3,6,0,48441,56] as $val){
    $heap->insert($val);
}
```

Now, collect the top 5.

```
<?php

$top_five = [];

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i){
    $top_five[] = $heap->extract();
}

print_r($top_five);
```